# How to navbar sticky over a slider image

Tags: css, navbar, sticky

I have a navbar like this, please look the picture

[image: sampel 1]

this is the css code

```
.home-upperbar-row{
    background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 15;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: unset;
  height: 100%;
  left: 1vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  transform: scale(1,1) translate(0%,0%);
}
```

I want the red marked part in the top image but doesn't change the scale, how?

more or less the desired look like this

the picture was obtained when I scroll on the page

[image: i want]

Comment: hi can you please provide full code on https://codepen.io/pen/ or fiddler. so we can help.

Comment: Please provide us with the HTML code.